# Rails outer join, left join or some other join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, left-join

Table selections

```
user_id
profile_id
```

Table profile

```
user_id
```

Table user

user has_one profile
profile belongs_to user
user has_many selections

How can I select ALL profiles that are NOT in selections table for a user?

Answer (score 1):

For a pure SQL method, which is practically always the fastest way of doing things with data, I would go with:

```
select *
from   profiles
where  id not in (
         select profile_id
         from   user_profiles
         where  user_id = #{self.id})
```

ActiveRecord syntax does better with joins, but I'd be inclined for simplicity and readability to keep it as:

```
Profile.where("id not in (
                 select profile_id
                 from   user_profiles
                 where  user_id = ?)", self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a round about way with extra iteration. But one that came to my mind.

```
Profile.all.reject{|pro| pro.selections.nil?}
```

Comment: ids =  Selections.where(user_id: self.id).map{|x|x["user_id"]}.uniq


     
     Profile.where(['id not in (?)', ids])

Answer (score 0):

```
 ids =  Selection.where(user_id: self.id).map{|x|x["user_id"]}.uniq

 Profile.where(['id not in (?)', ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

David answer is the most correct of all answers, though I wanted to contribute on a bit of a tuning. If You are using postgres than this post is worth reading:
http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Basically the gist of what that article says is, that are 3 usual ways to do it:

- NOT IN (already suggested by David)
- NOT EXISTS
- LEF JOIN and checking fro NULLs

The author does some research and comes up with conclusion **that second and third produce the same explain plan**, which means that both are virtually the same.

Revising Davids example it would look like this

```
Profile.where(
  "
     NOT EXISTS (
       select 1
       from selections
       where selections.user_id = ? AND selections.profile_id = profiles.id)
  ", id) # no need to use self when calling instance methods
```